# How do I log response in Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, rest, logging

I am using RestTemplate to make calls to a web service.

```
String userId = restTemplate.getForObject(createUserUrl, String.class);
```

If this fails to return a user ID I just get returned null but I don't know why. How do I output the actual XML response to a log?

Comment: You can also use LoggingRequestInterceptor

cf http://stackoverflow.com/a/22620168/409784

Comment: Resolved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952154/spring-resttemplate-how-to-enable-full-debugging-logging-of-requests-responses/47467572

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on which method of making the HTTP connection you are using, you could look at turning up the logging within the actual HTTP connection classes.

For example, if you are using commons HttpClient, you can set

```
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=DEBUG
```

The commons-httpclient project has [an entire page in the documentation on their logging practices](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/logging.html).

Comment: I don't know what method I'm using, it's all under the hood of RestTemplate. Using log4j.logger.httpclient.wire doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I suggest first turning up logging for ALL of Spring to understand what is going on under the hood of RestTemplate, this might give you an idea of where to go next.

Answer (score 9):

Configure your logging as follows:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.client=DEBUG
```

Then use a curl command to see the output, eg

```
curl  -H 'Accept: application/xml' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' http://localhost:8080/ser/data
```

By default, restTemplate uses HttpURlConnection (via SimpleClientHttpRequest), so you might need to switch to jakarta httpclient to see the log statement. Otherwise the above log configuration will out show you the response

```
    <bean id="httpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <constructor-arg><bean  class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient"/></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="httpClientFactory"/>
        <property name="messageConverters">
...
```

Comment: That log4j setting logs the requests but not the responses. I can't use curl because it is a Windows environment, plus I'm looking for something I could commit as part of the codebase so that the logging is enabled for our integration tests

Comment: There are Windows versions of curl, and also cygwin versions: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win32

Answer (score 3):

You can use [spring-rest-template-logger](https://github.com/markhobson/spring-rest-template-logger) to log `RestTemplate` HTTP traffic.

Add a dependency to your Maven project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hobsoft.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rest-template-logger</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then customize your `RestTemplate` as follows:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
    .customizers(new LoggingCustomizer())
    .build()
```

Ensure that debug logging is enabled in `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.hobsoft.spring.resttemplatelogger.LoggingCustomizer = DEBUG
```

Now all RestTemplate HTTP traffic will be logged to `org.hobsoft.spring.resttemplatelogger.LoggingCustomizer` at debug level.

DISCLAIMER: I wrote this library.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17802986)

Comment: @Al-Mothafar Thanks, I've included the relevant information here.

Answer (score 0):

If you used swagger to generate the RestTemplate based client then in the ApiClient there is a public method setDebugging and you can set to true or false and then I was able to see whats going on.
Hope this helps.
I used latest swager generator cli I think its 2.9 or something

Answer (score 0):

For the Apache HttpClient v4 factory:

```
final RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
    .requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory())
    .build();
```

the Apache lib has:

```
public class ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory
...
    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection.class);
    private final Log headerLog = LogFactory.getLog("org.apache.http.headers");
    private final Log wireLog = LogFactory.getLog("org.apache.http.wire");
```

So define loggers `org.apache.http.headers` & `org.apache.http.wire` at DEBUG level!

Answer (score -3):

you don't need to write a single line of code,
you just need to add the following property in application.properties file

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate=DEBUG
```

using this it will log rest template call's request body, request header, request URL, and response body also in debug mode.

Comment: Yes, this will do it. check it out.

Comment: I did and ask on my machine it only logs URL, status code, and JSON mapping model class name