# Logging RestTemplate requests

Tags: java, debugging, logging, resttemplate

I want to log requests made by my RestTemplate and log time taken to fetch a response.

Currently I do not see a way to get the complete request url except by turning on the debug log for the REST template in logback.xml

```
<logger name="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate" level="DEBUG" />
```

There are two issues here:
1. Since I am working in a multithreaded environment I am unable to correlate the logs to the request I am making
2. I want the RestTemplate DEBUG statements to be logged for a particular class alone and not for every class utilizing the RestTemplate

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952154/spring-resttemplate-how-to-enable-full-debugging-logging-of-requests-responses

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892018/how-do-i-log-response-in-spring-resttemplate/